# How to properly deploy Spring Cloud services to AWS ECS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, spring-cloud

I've spent the last week trying to find a good example on how to properly achieve this but the internet doesn't seem to have anything out there...

I have what I'd say is a pretty basic Spring Cloud service. It includes Eureka, Zuul, Spring Config, and a handful of services.

I've worked out using the `esc-cli` how I can easily create new tasks based on my `docker-compose.yml` files. So I have two tasks

A management task which has basic things that at this stage don't need to scale, and having one instance of them is just fine for this project.

```
version: '2'
services:

  mongo:
    image: mongo
    cpu_shares: 300
    mem_limit: 268435456
    ports:
      - 27017:27017   

  config-service:
    image: config-service
    cpu_shares: 300
    mem_limit: 268435456
    ports:
      - 8888:8888
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=cloud

  edge-service:
    image: edge-service
    cpu_shares: 300
    mem_limit: 268435456
    ports:
      - 80:8080
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=cloud
```

My second task has the clients of the above task.

```
version: '2'
services:

  instance-service:
    image: instance-service
    cpu_shares: 300
    mem_limit: 268435456
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=cloud

  restore-service:
    image: restore-service:latest
    cpu_shares: 300
    mem_limit: 268435456
    ports:
      - 8082:8082
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=cloud
```

I can easily create these tasks with a simple command such as `ecs-cli compose --file management-task.yml --project-name management-task up` No problem there.

Where I hit an issue nothing can reach the `Eureka` or the `Config` services, so they all die. I've read all over the place that I can use an application load balance to allow the containers to talk to each other, however I can't actually find any information on **how** to do this.

The closest I've managed to find is a blog post here http://www.rahulkatte.com/index.html#!/microservice-part-V however they're not making use of Eureka being inside a task, nor a config server.

So, is there any comprehensive examples out there on how exactly you deploy a modern Spring Cloud app to AWS? Or does anyone have any pointers as to how to get my tasks/containers talking to each other, without just saying "Use a load balancers..."?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I know this is sort of necro'ing a post, but there are no answers on here yet, so for posterity of anyone finding it in the future:

You're dealing with a "service discovery" problem here, and there are multiple ways to solve it:

1. You can use load balancers as you state. The way you do this is by creating an ALB, then creating a target group within that ALB. The target group's health check must the string literal "traffic port", because each ECS container will have a random port. Make sure that the security group for the EC2 instances attached to your ECS cluster allow incoming on all TCP ports. Note that if your ALB health check fails for whatever reason, the container will set to "draining" and be shut down.
2. ECS also recently (after your post, but is now GA) announced ECS service discovery. [See this post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-ecs-service-discovery/).
3. You could use Kubernetes (EKS), which supports service discovery natively.